# BC30201 Expression expected in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, expression, iif-function

I am using Power BI expression and I get this error: [BC30201] Expression expected
for the following expression:

*=iif ( Fields!DriftCorrection_pH4Value.Value== Blank(),
(Fields!DriftCorrection_pH7Value.Value +Fields!DriftCorrection_pH10Value.Value)/2.0,
(Fields!DriftCorrection_pH7Value.Value +Fields!DriftCorrection_pH4Value.Value)/2.0)*

Could you please help? Thanks in advance.